# Two context objects in a single jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to do give a jQuery selector two objects for context. The following snippet works but lacks a certain finesse in its syntax.

```
 jQ('#some_id_or_selector', first_jQ_obj.add(second_jQ_obj) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using comma separated context like below,

```
$('someselector', 'context1, context2')
```

or Simply,

```
$('context1, context2').find('someselector')
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ud4MU/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ud4MU/1/

**Note:** If it is some ID in your selector, then you can select the element by ID as `$('#some_id')` instead of using any context.

Since you have jQuery objects you can do like below,

```
$context1.add($context2).find('selector');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ud4MU/3/

Comment: This is good! Though I already have to jQobjects saved as variables. I don't really want to search the DOM tree again for them. I will use this in the future. Is there a way to do your first example with the two Objects as the context instead off a single selector?

Comment: I wish I could +1 your edit because you state that if it is an ID you are looking for. Very precise.

Comment: This again works, your insight from your first example is the closest to what I was looking for. I think I might just be asking for something that doesn't exist. Something like this jQ('someselector', $one $two);

Comment: @CynicalOptimist yea, I don't think it is a valid syntax. It expects a single argument.

Comment: Ya not valid, just hopping there was an alternative that did work, I'll accept you're answer Vega as it is the closest to what I was looking for, although I think what I really wanted doesn't exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about `.find()` function

```
first_jQ_obj.add(second_jQ_obj).find('#some_id_or_selector' )
```

But the **ID** in the HTML page should be **unique**..

So

`jQ('#some_id_or_selector')`  should be sufficient

Comment: filter is not equal to the context selector.. since filter will only return if the first or second element matches the filter selector.. you probably want .find() instead

Comment: that works but i believe that a context selector is faster that a .find() is it not?

Comment: Internally context selector uses the find method

Comment: maybe this isn't right but this makes me favor context selectors... http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel

Plus I like context selectors syntax better :)

Comment: If you check out the jQuery.js file , context selectors use .find() internally

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
jQ('selector, selector, selector').doStuff(....
```

You can also use heirarchy -

```
jQ('parent', 'descnedants').doStuff(...
```

(corrected comma placement)

Comment: I think #2 should read jQ('parent','descendants').doStuff(... no?

Comment: Yeah - I'll fix. Just typing too quickly.